# Windows notebook power consumption monitor

Tags: windows-7, power, monitoring

Is there some kind of SW similar to Android phone's power monitor?

I would like to know the amount of power the wifi/various applications have taken.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your PC laptop has Windows OS installed you can use 'powercfg -energy' command from command prompt (cmd.exe).

If you have Linux - use 'powertop'

Comment: Link no work....

Comment: Just a note, this is Windows 10 specific and requires Administrator access.